# difference between ISLOCALNAME and ISGUID in AID constructor

Tags: java, agents-jade

i want to know what is the difference between  ISLOCALNAME and ISGUID

1)
`AID df = new AID("agent1", AID.ISLOCALNAME);

```
   System.out.println(df.getName());`
```

2)`AID df = new AID("agent1", AID.ISGUID);

```
   System.out.println(df.getName());`
```

thank you !

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know ISLOCALNAME indicates that the passed name is local name in Home Agent Platform and ISGUID - a globally unique identifier.

"If the name is a local name, then the HAP (Home Agent Platform) is concatenated to the name, separated by  "@"." (from javadocs)